# Why is Max Value not showing any value in the summary metric?

Tags: newrelic-platform

Only `Average Value` is displayed, I cannot get it working with `Max Value`

Is this by design or am I doing something wrong?
(I tried sending the metric with *unit* count, value, or an arbitrary string, same result in each case)

Comment: I'm using the Java SDK. I noticed that the mongo plugin seems to do this, but they call the api directly via http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is a bug that is preventing this from working correctly. The New Relic team is aware and working on this issue.

https://newrelic.com/docs/plugin-dev/known-platform-limitations#max-min-not-reliable